# Problem with ActionMailer in Rails3. (ssl hostname was not match with the server certificate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-3

strange error here, I setup an mailer to send a confirmation to the user after signing up in my rails3 app, it worked some days ago, now after moving it to another server and adding different other features i tried it again today and i get this error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in UsersController#create 
hostname was not match with the server certificate
```

My initializers/setup_mail.rb file looks like this

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp # be sure to choose SMTP delivery
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "mailout.eve-images.de",  
  :port                 => 587,  
  :domain               => "eve-images.de",  
  :user_name            => "xxxxxxx-noreply",  
  :password             => "xxxxxxxx",  
  :authentication       => "plain", 
  :enable_starttls_auto =>  true   
}
```

My mailers/user_mailer.rb file

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base  
  default :from => "no-reply@eve-images.de"  

  def registration_confirmation(user)  
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")  
  end  
end
```

and my users_controller

```
 def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver  
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:notice] = "Thank you for signing up! You are now logged in."
      redirect_to "/"
    else
      ....
    end
  end
```

I tried already to set the :enable_starttls_auto to false and got the same error.
Also I want my pw and user to be encrypted...

Any ideas are really appreciated!

Here is the full strack trace if it helps

```
/Users/eveadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:121:in `post_connection_check'
mail (2.2.15) lib/mail/core_extensions/smtp.rb:16:in `tlsconnect'
/Users/eveadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:566:in `do_start'
/Users/eveadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:525:in `start'
mail (2.2.15) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:127:in `deliver!'
mail (2.2.15) lib/mail/message.rb:1967:in `do_delivery'
mail (2.2.15) lib/mail/message.rb:228:in `block in deliver'
actionmailer (3.0.3) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:401:in `block in deliver_mail'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionmailer (3.0.3) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:399:in `deliver_mail'
mail (2.2.15) lib/mail/message.rb:228:in `deliver'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23:in `create'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:435:in `_run__2864349735198625628__process_action__3535857296079828011__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:120:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'
haml (3.0.25) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'
client_side_validations (3.0.4) lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:295:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:353:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/Users/eveadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/eveadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/eveadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

solution:

```
:openssl_verify_mode => 'none'
```

Comment: I don't like the suggestion of disabling security being the accepted answer, without any explanation as to *why* this is suggested, and what the cause of the problem is.

Comment: HI Let me know if there any problem with this setting and how would you recognize that

Comment: There is an [explanation here](https://davidroetzel.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/rails-3-actionmailer-tls-certificate-verification/). The proposed solution is valid only for the Mailer gem (that is, Rails 3+).

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```rb
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

Not

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Comment: Definitely a better solution if your mail server is running locally and doesn't need to accept external connections.

Comment: @BrendonMuir May I ask if using actionmailer -> postfix -> sendgrid means "running locally"?

Comment: Holey Moley! I can't remember :D I use postmark now and they have their own delivery method in their gem `:postmark`. I think what I meant was that if you aren't connecting to another server to send your emails (i.e. with smtp) then the `:sendmail` method seemed to be simpler (no credentials required). I'm not sure what I meant about the external connections part :) Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, though Franks solution didn't work for me.  I found a solutions that is along the same path.

```
:enable_starttls_auto => false # changed from true
```

reference: https://gist.github.com/1021285

Answer (score 1):

For me `:enable_starttls_auto => false` didn't worked and I left it `:enable_starttls_auto => true`. But the thing I had gotten wrong was that in `devise.rb` I hadn't uncommented this line: `config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"`. When I removed the comment everything worked on my localhost. On the other hand when on the machine where I host my site I still get this error.